# HierarchyRequestError during jQuery replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, domexception

I want to go through all the child  elements of a div whose id is 'imgDiv', and replace  all of them with a new element created by wrap the image with an parent anchor . Like `<image src=...>` to `<a href=...><image ...></a>`. The code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elem = $('.imgDiv');
    $(elem).children('.image').each(function(){
            var src = $(this).attr('src');//get the src of a image
            console.log(src);
            var fancyAnchor = $(document.createElement('a')).addClass('fancybox');//create an anchor parent of this image
            //add some attr to meet the need of the lib
            fancyAnchor.attr('data-fancybox-group', 'gallery');
            fancyAnchor.attr('href', src);
            //append this to the anchor
            fancyAnchor.append(this);
            //replace this with the new created anchor <a>
            $(this).replaceWith(fancyAnchor);
        });
  });
```

The error is strange, I think is this something caused by each function ?

```
http://images.craigslist.org/3F53If3J85Nd5Ic5L2d5q499af1a13b10124e.jpg test.js:5
Uncaught Error: HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3 jquery.js:5
x.fn.extend.replaceWith jquery.js:5
x.fn.extend.domManip jquery.js:5
x.fn.extend.replaceWith jquery.js:5
(anonymous function) test.js:13
x.extend.each jquery.js:4
x.fn.x.each jquery.js:4
(anonymous function) test.js:3
x.Callbacks.l jquery.js:4
x.Callbacks.c.fireWith jquery.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery.js:4
S jquery.js:4
```

And if you want to debug, here is an excerpt of a HTML page

```
<body>
<div class="srchDiv"><p class="row" data-pid="3831489360"> <a href="/gbs/cto/3831489360.html" class="i" data-id="3F53If3J85Nd5Ic5L2d5q499af1a13b10124e.jpg"></a> <span class="pl"> <span class="star v" title="save this post in your favorites list"></span>  <a href="/gbs/cto/3831489360.html">1980 DATSUN 210</a> </span> <span class="l2"> <span class="pnr">  <span class="pp"></span> <small> (BOSTON)</small> <span class="px"> <span class="p"> pic</span></span> </span>  </span> </p><span class="msgSpan">Year: 1980</span><div class="imgDiv"><img class="image" src="http://images.craigslist.org/3F53If3J85Nd5Ic5L2d5q499af1a13b10124e.jpg"><img class="image" src="http://images.craigslist.org/3Kc3L53Jc5N45Ea5F7d5q7913e0d4462611cf.jpg"><img class="image" src="http://images.craigslist.org/3G23Ld3Jf5I95G45K8d5qe8c553cf8b961548.jpg"><img class="image" src="http://images.craigslist.org/3Kf3F73N85I25Gc5E7d5q80635196e0161ab7.jpg"><br><img class="image" src="http://images.craigslist.org/3E73Ge3L55L85Kb5H3d5qdf21ef9bd8c31c0d.jpg"><img class="image" src="http://images.craigslist.org/3Ec3G13J95Lf5K45M6d5q917b9e39d65217bd.jpg"><img class="image" src="http://images.craigslist.org/3Ff3L83Hd5L75I75E8d5q9a2b1c55c74710b5.jpg"><img class="image" src="http://images.craigslist.org/3Ef3Gb3H35La5I65H3d5q57b390b1f8ce1389.jpg"></div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to replace `this` by the element to which you appended it, and by appending an element you, in fact, move it, and thus, here, remove it from the DOM, hence the error.

Replace

```
fancyAnchor.append(this);
$(this).replaceWith(fancyAnchor);
```

with

```
$(this).wrap(fancyAnchor);
```

Comment: Also, `$(elem).children('.image')...` should be `elem.children('.image')...`

Comment: @Mysteryos Both work but you're right, this would be cleaner.

Comment: I don't really get it. So is it something like reference or value problem? When I append `this` to the anchor, actually `this` is a reference to the `<image>`, and I replace it then cause an error?

Comment: So basically, I didn't copy `this`?

Comment: append doesn't copy an element but moves it.

Comment: @zoujyjs Incidentally, replacing `fancyAnchor.append(this)` with `fancyAnchor.append($(this).clone());` works perfectly, which illustrates that the problem here is simply that you're moving the element rather than copying it, and that but for that misconception your logic would have worked fine. Using `wrap` is of course cleaner, though.

Comment: @MarkAmery Ok, now I get it. Thank you and dystroy  for your enlightening answer

Answer (score -1):

Don't use $(this).replace or whatever changes the DOM inside a each.

EDIT: seems it's not the issue

>

I would also suggest using $.each(...,f) instead of $(...).each(f).

Also you whould consider the [wrap function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) instead of $.each, it does exactly what you need :

```
$(elem).children('.image').wrap(function(){
            return $('<a>').addClass('fancybox').attr('data-fancybox-group', 'gallery').attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));
        });
```

Comment: -1 for not explaining the actual cause of the error, and for the vague suggestion that you shouldn't make DOM changes within a `.each` call. I can't see any reason not to do so, and the OP's problem could have happened in exactly the same way outside of a `.each`. The `.each` is irrelevant here.

Comment: @MarkAmery Sorry, Maybe it's my fault in the question saying that **The error is strange, I think is this something caused by each function ?**, this may mislead TecHunter

Comment: @zoujyjs thx for defending me but he was right, I should have read carefully the append then replaceWith is the problem